# In c++, how to send data fetched by dll to exe

Tags: c++, dll

I'm a beginner in C++, fed up with errors faced during Data transmission from dll to exe.

***Problem :***
I have an exe in which i had bundled a dll... Now the exe wanna initiate the dll to fetch some datas from Active Directory.. This is performed by using Function pointer call from exe to dll.. Now, dll fetches data from AD and whenever it attains a Limit (100 data ), it should go to exe to print this data(Only in exe i needed to perform this printing of datas)... and again it should return to dll and continue to fetch datas,,

***How to transfer data from dll to exe...??????????***

FYI : I had tried using Structure and a class which is common for both exe and dll... 
but the memory clean up process crashes my program,, As the heap for dll and exe are different.. the data which i give inside dll are tried to cleanup in exe... (This is a different topic and this needs more explanation... and inorder not to waste ur valuable time kindly help me with the easiest way to transfer data from dll to exe)

I couldnt post my program because of restrictions in my organisation.. Kindly give me a better solution to this...

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate a memory block in exe, pass the address to dll, dll can fill data into the memory, then you can release the buffer in exe.

In your dll, you can export an interface like:

```
void fill_buffer( char * p_buff, int buff_size );
```

In your exe, you can allocate a buffer and pass it to the dll, then cleanup it:

```
char * the_buff = new char[1024];

while (...) {
    fill_buffer( the_buff, 1024 );

    //do something to the_buff
    print(the_buff)
}

delete []the_buff;
```

When you pass structure or class between dll and exe, be careful that the byte alignment should be consistent in them.

And for your question, maybe you can paste some fake code, then your problem will be clearer.